# $u_n\to u$ weakly in $X$ implies $u_n\to u$ weakly in $Y$, $X\subset Y$ compactly embedded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence, compact-operators

Let $X$ and $Y$ be (reflexive) Banach spaces. Assume that $X$ is compactly embedded in $Y$. Consider a sequance $(u_n)\subset X$, $u_n\to u$ weakly in $X$. Why compact embedding implies that $u_n\to u$ weakly in $Y$? Where the compactness is used?

Comment: you dont need the compactness for that . But instead you get the strong convergence in Y using Compactness

Comment: I think that continuity is enough. Take any $f\in Y^*$ and consider $f\circ i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is how can use the compactness: $u_n \to u$ strongly in Y up to extraction of subsequnce**

$ u_n\to u$ weakly  in X implies $(u_n) $ is bounded in X.

But X is compactly embedded in Y, therefore there exists a subsequence $u_{n_j}$ which converges strongly in Y to some $y\in Y$

But also $ u_n\to u$ weakly  in Y **(simply by continuity)** Hence, $u=y$

that is $u_{n_j} \to u$ strongly in Y.